# Is there a way to find out if an IP address belongs to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, operating-system, ip-address, nmap

I am trying to find a simple way to check if an IP address belongs to an iPhone.
A solution that I can imagine is to use nmap to determine the operating
system of the specified IP address and then check whether it's iOS..
Is this a right way? Otherwise, could anyone suggest me an alternative way?

Thank you,
Thanasis

Comment: Is this from the point of view of a server app, maybe HTTP ? If so, the HTTP headers may help.

Comment: I don't think there is a subset reserved for iPhones. You'll probably be best inspecting the HTTP headers as above, or the user agent string sent with requests, but both can be easily spoofed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [nmap does fingerprint iOS](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r19869534-An-iPhone-Scanned-with-Nmap).

Answer (score 0):

We can get the IP address by this code:

```
- (NSString *)getIPAddress
    {
        NSString *address = @"error";
        struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
        struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
        int success = 0;

        // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
        success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
        if (success == 0) {
            // Loop through linked list of interfaces
            temp_addr = interfaces;
            while (temp_addr != NULL) {
                if( temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                    // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                    if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                        // Get NSString from C String
                        address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                    }
                }

                temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
            }
        }

        // Free memory
        freeifaddrs(interfaces);

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but this code gets the IP address if run on a device.. What I was looking for, is a way to find if a given IP address belongs to an iphone, without having access to the device. I mean to do it remotely with somekind of scan..